# Text fields as collections symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I have to create form from Product and collection with text fields as array from TechChar

**Entity**

Product

```
<?php

namespace Homework\Bundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Homework\Bundle\Entity\TechChar;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="products")
 */
class Product {

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", name="name")
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", name="brand")
     */
    protected $brand;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", name="price")
     */
    protected $price;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="is_active")
     */
    protected $isActive;

     /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="TechChar")
     *  @ORM\JoinTable(name="products_tech_char",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="tech_char_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     */

    protected $techChar;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->techChar = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function getBrand() {
        return $this->brand;
    }

    public function getPrice() {
        return $this->price;
    }

    public function getIsActive() {
        return $this->isActive;
    }

    public function getTechChar() {
        return $this->techChar;
    }

    public function setName($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function setBrand($brand) {
        $this->brand = $brand;
    }

    public function setPrice($price) {
        $this->price = $price;
    }

    public function setIsActive($isActive) {
        $this->isActive = $isActive;
    }

    public function setTechChar($techChar) {
        $this->techChar = $techChar;
    }

}
```

TechChar

```
<?php

namespace Homework\Bundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="tech_char")
 */
class TechChar {

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", name="name")
     */
    protected $name;

     /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Product", mappedBy="id")
     */
    protected $product;

    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
    public function getProduct() {
        return $this->product;
    }

    public function setProduct($product) {
        $this->product = $product;
    }


}
```

Also i've create FormType

```
namespace Homework\Bundle\Forms;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
class FormType extends AbstractType {
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $techChar = $em->getRepository("HomeworkBundle:TechChar")->findAll();
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($techChar);
        echo '</pre>';
        $builder->add('Namesss');
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'HomeWork\Bundle\Entity\TechChar',
        ));
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'technicals';
    }

}
```

And PanelColntroller

```
class PanelController extends Controller {
   public function addProducts(Request $request) {
        $product = new Product();
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
//        $techChars = $em->getRepository("HomeworkBundle:TechChar")->findAll();
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($product)
                ->add('Name', 'text')
                ->add('Brand', 'choice', array(
                    'choices' => array('hitachi' => 'Hitachi', 'midea' => 'Midea', 'panasonic' => 'Panasonic', 'ligi' => 'LG')))
                ->add('Price', 'text')
                ->add('isActive', 'checkbox')
                ->add('techChar','collection',array('type'=>new FormType()) )
                ->add('save', 'submit')
                ->getForm();

        if ($form->isValid()) {

            $em->persist($form->getData());
            $em->flush();
        }
        return $this->render('HomeworkBundle:Default:add.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
    }

}
```

I have to make textfields where labels are 'name' from TechChar
Example:
http://centur.bg/Form.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have separated your problem in 3 entities:

```
class Product {
    /** @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Product") */
    protected $productTechChars;
}

class ProductTechChar {
    /** @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product") */
    protected $product;
    /** @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product") */
    protected $techChar;
    /** @ORM\ManyToOne(type="string") */
    protected $textField;
}

class TechChar {
    /** @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Product") */
    protected $productTechChars;
}
```

Like this you have you "TechChar" Entity with a list of technical charaterics name and you then use the "ProductTechChar" to do the bridge between these two entities and set your text field.